Is this crack in my block foundation a cause for concern?
When working in my basement today, I noticed a very long, horizontal hairline crack at about my eye level (I'm 5'2") in a row of mortar between the cinder block. Following the crack along the wall, I found a stair step hairline crack in my laundry room (also in my basement) coming from approximately where my outdoor spicket is. How concerned should I be?
The hairline horizontal crack is approximately 10-15'. I've already started to try and reach out to some structural engineers because of my paranoia.





Hairline cracks are a bit common.  They become a concern below ground since water has an easier way in.

Is the block wall filled with concrete?  Fully/partially/minimal/not-at-all ?

Um, to be honest I don't know.

I added a new photo to show what I could see inside part of the cinderblock I could get to. It looks like it's filled with something, but I can't really tell what it is.

What I see wouldn't be a huge cause for concern.  It would be a cause for monitoring, though.

Joint cracks are very common in block basements. They don't necessarily indicate a structural problem. Since mortar joints don't handle movement well, any settling or shifting after construction results in cracks. The foundation still supports the house just fine.
Problems are indicated if there's movement, or if there's substantial displacement of the wall. If you don't see change over time, worry not.
